# Round Color Picker with simple colors

Tags: angularjs, cordova, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

I've searched for many color pickers and only found squared color pickers and others which has many color variations. I'm searching for an specific kind of palette colors as this:

[image]

Does someone know a plug-in in Angular JS to use this kind of palette? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can use any color picker script in own custom directive if you can't find one already wrapped in an angular module

Comment: But be careful – on your picture you have wrong colors direction. For example in HSL color model yellow is after red and not before. Look **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43376290/9801830)** for correct colors direction.

Answer (score 0):

A year too late, but I think you meant Angular Color Picker, the GitHub repository is [here](https://github.com/ruhley/angular-color-picker).
If you set the 'Round' option to Yes, you will get the circular color picker.

However I must say that there are better ones out there. Take a look at this [overview](http://angularjs.jqueryrain.com/demo/color-picker/) of 10+ Angular Color Pickers. Some of the Color Pickers mentioned there are:

- [Angular Radial Color Picker](https://github.com/talamaska/angular-radial-color-picker)
- [ui.bootstrap.materialPicker](https://github.com/Templarian/ui.bootstrap.materialPicker)
- [md-color-picker](https://github.com/brianpkelley/md-color-picker)

Comment: Please add the relevant snippets from your links.  If the links you reference ever change, your answer won't be very useful.

Comment: I really don't know how to post snippets of a blog post with a bunch of demos. I have added some extra info, but it's still just links as the OP asked for an existing plugin, not to create one. Could you give me an example of what you want me to add?