# How to draw a circle with a radial gradient on the canvas?

Tags: c++, xaml, canvas, uwp, c++-cx

I need to draw a circle with a radial gradient on the canvas in my custom control (XAML). But `Windows::UI::Xaml::Media` contains `LinearGradientBrush` only. I know about design guids but my control requires so feature to the user can see the color gamma.
Below that I need to get:
[image: Gradient]
**P.S.** I ask how to draw it at least programmaticaly without XAML.
**P.P.S.** I know that I can draw a picture in some editor with radial gradient and after draw it on the canvas but it seems not good solution for the adaptive design.

Comment: Please make an effort to make clearer what you are asking. At least paste any code containing the things you had already tried. I am in doubt about what technology you are making the question about: is it Visual C++|MFC; or is it WPF|XAML|C#; or is it Managed-C++|C++/CLI?

Comment: I updated my post to make it clearer.

Comment: Adding an image doesn't clarify more the question. Did you put any code with any code you actually tried? **NO**. Are people willing to help you having any idea what technology you want to use to solve your problem? **NO**.

Comment: How can I post a code? I don't know any solution. Although, I found Win2D library now and as I understood it's a single way. But for me it's strange, it's the first platform where I can't draw radial or canonical gradients

Answer (score 1):

You can check the [`RenderColorPickerHueRing()`](https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit/blob/master/WinRTXamlToolkit/Imaging/WriteableBitmapColorPickerExtensions.cs) method for a sample of how you could do it on a CPU in a `WriteableBitmap`. It's not super fast (at least in the C# version), but at least it saves you from packaging another image with your app or from using DirectX, which is a bit more tricky to get set up correctly and stabilize.